# Sharing Cisco VPN connection with network peers

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn, connection-sharing

We have a Windows Seven host with Cisco VPN Client access configured.
We want to share this connection with some linux machines.

We tried sharing the Lan connection (GUI option), then adding the windows machine to the routing tables on the linux machines in order to redirect traffic through the VPN using the Windows Machine as a gateway.

But W7 is not forwarding.

We modified the registry record by hand:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ Tcpip \ Parameters \  IPEnableRouter = 1

Now Cisco VPN Client is not connecting (lol)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

> Any thoughts?

Don't do this. Either configure a client-based VPN connection for each host that you want to connect with, or configure a site-to-site VPN and bridge both sites in question. Windows 7 was not ever intended to be used the way that you're describing.

Answer (score 4):

The Cisco AnyConnect client will not even install if you have Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) enabled. It's not supported at all. Get a firewall and set up a site-to-site VPN.